# Get first item from each list in a column of lists in a Pandas dataframe with some empty lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like the following:

| Column A |
| --- |
| ['A','B'] |
| [] |

I would like to get the first item from each list so that it would look like this:

| First A |
| --- |
| 'A' |
| '' |

I have tried several things, but the most recent is:
df['First A'] = df['Column A'].str.list[0]

I get this error:
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

It seems that I only get the error when trying to pull the value from the empty lists.

Comment: If they are actually lists, then `df['First A'] = df['Column A'].str[0].fillna('')` will give you your desired result, or you can use one of the other methods in the posted duplicate